# Finding dates between two dates (Best practice)

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have 2 SQL scripts. One like this:

```
"Date" > '2014-04-11' AND "Date" <= '2014-04-12'
```

the other one like this:

```
"Date" BETWEEN '2014-04-11' AND '2014-04-12'
```

Now i wonder if there is any specific best practice, one reason to do one over the other and if one of them is better for some apparent reason I missed somewhere down the road.

Comment: Those two queries are not synonymous. `BETWEEN` is inclusive of both arguments. I'd recommend reading these two articles; [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), and [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries). Although written for SQL Server, many of the arguments are still valid for Oracle.

Comment: Not *quite* synonymous; the first one has `>` rather than `>=`, which may be a mistake in the question. It's not entirely clear which data you want either to find though. (I'd also suggest you don't use quoted identifiers or implicit date conversions, but both are outside the scope of the question).

Comment: Thanks for the links, i was looking for this subject for a good while, but my "GoogleFu" didn't find anything in this matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking for best practices.  I think the following is the best practice:

```
"Date" >= DATE '2014-04-11' AND "Date" < DATE '2014-04-12' + 1
```

First, note the use of the `DATE` keyword.  You question is about *dates* and yet you are using a date format that Oracle does not directly support.  Happily, Oracle support the ANSI standard `DATE` keyword with the ISO standard format.

Second, I added a `+1` so you can see the end of the time period, which is presumably what you want to see in the code.  It shouldn't affect performance because the `+ 1` is on a constant.

Third, a date constant has a time component.  When none is specified, it is midnight on the date.  So, the expression:

```
"Date" BETWEEN '2014-04-11' AND '2014-04-12'
```

Is really:

```
"Date" >= TIMESTAMP '2014-04-11 00:00:00' AND "Date" <= TIMESTAMP '2014-04-12 00:00:00'
```

That is, exactly one time from the later date is included, the first instant at midnight.  This is not usually what you want.  Oracle makes this problem worse in two ways:

1. The `date` data type includes a time component.
2. The default way of presenting `date` values has no time component.

So, to be safest, use the following rules:

- Do not use `between` on dates.
- Use `>=` for the first date.
- User `<` for the second.

Aaron Bertrand has a [blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) on exactly this topic.  Although it is specifically about SQL Server, many of the ideas apply to Oracle -- especially because the `date` data type in Oracle includes times.

Comment: "Date" was abstract, but since the original column name made no sense in this context i took the liberty to change it in to something more readable, though not so correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> create table date_tab as select sysdate + level d from dual connect by rownum < 10;

Table created.
```

Using between:

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly
SQL> select * from date_tab where d between sysdate + 1 and sysdate + 3;


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 290508398

...

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(SYSDATE@!+1<=SYSDATE@!+3)
   2 - filter("D">=SYSDATE@!+1 AND "D"<=SYSDATE@!+3)
```

Using date intervals:

```
SQL> select * from date_tab where d > sysdate + 1 and d <= sysdate + 3;


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 290508398

...

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(SYSDATE@!+1<SYSDATE@!+3)
   2 - filter("D">SYSDATE@!+1 AND "D"<=SYSDATE@!+3)
```

As you can see, oracle optimizer rewrites the `between` predicate to `"D">=SYSDATE@!+1 AND "D"<=SYSDATE@!+3` So if you use the second variant oracle performs less action than the first variant for one step.