# Searching records that match a set of ranges with good performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a currency exchanges table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE CurrencyExchanges
(
    Id int,
    FromCurrency uniqueidentifier,
    ToCurrency uniqueidentifier,
    RateDate date,
    Value int
);
```

I want to query this table for currency exchanges across a time span or for a single date. For instance, all records with `RateDate >= '2019-03-27'` and `RateDate <= '2019-03-31'` *or* `RateDate  >= '2019-03-01'` and `RateDate <= '2019-03-28'`. Notice that they may overlap. Now, I know I can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM CurrencyExchanges
WHERE (RateDate >= '2019-03-27' AND RateDate <= '2019-03-31')
   OR (RateDate >= '2019-03-01' AND RateDate <= '2019-03-28')
```

But the problem is that I will be passing a list of these date ranges to the query, and they may be several. So I'd have to add to the where clause a list of about ~1000 `OR` conditions. I'm worried about how performant having 1000 conditions in the where clause may be. I was wondering if there is an alternative, like using `IN` for scalar values, or another alternative.

Any ideas? Would I take a high performance hit if I use that list of `OR` conditions approach?

Thanks

Comment: If you have a dynamically sized list of date ranges, you must therefore have an application that's taking the list and dynamically writing the SQL?  If that's the case the best place to collapse these ranges out is in the application.  Sort them, overlap them, collapse them down to non-overlapping ranges.  You can then use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE x BETWEEN y AND z   UNION ALL   SELECT * FROM table WHERE x BETWEEN y AND z   UNION ALL  etc, etc` with non-overlapping date ranges.  I wouldn't expect a dramatic performance delta though.

Comment: can you create a range of dates? like process your dates and use BETWEEN ??

Comment: @HasanMahmood, [best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25605865/5790584) is `>=` and `<`, not `BETWEEN` with regard to dates. Otherwise, the time component can yield unexpected results.

Comment: @MatBailie I was concerned about using that approach. I'm sending batches of 1000 ranges to this query, so that would result in a query with 1000 `UNION`s. You don't think performance would take a big hit?

Comment: @EricBrandt - Agreed, but the OP already is using `>= AND <=`, so is already using `BETWEEN`.  The data type is also `DATE` rather than `DATETIME`, so ***at present*** that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Heathcliff - By your own admission there will likely be overlaps.  If you do as I suggested, your application layer would identify the overlaps and collapse them out.  Your example would then become `(RateDate >= '2019-03-01' AND RateDate <= '2019-03-31')`.  That will reduce the number of `UNION ALL` queries, and by using `UNION ALL` you avoid the `OR` messing up the query planner.  Take it in two steps: eliminate the overlaps in your application, then try using `OR` vs using `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Should also try a single min/max covering the 1000 ranges.  If the percentage of desired records extracted from the entire single contiguous region is over some value (say 20%) then it may be faster to just query that single range and sort it out in the application as needed.  However avoid this technique if there is an outlier.  Recommend to compare the execution plans in SSMS or SQL Sentry on a worst case query.  An index should be created on the date field for all the approaches (no one has mentioned that yet).

Comment: Here's a suggestion... put your date ranges into a table with columns "StartDt" and "EndDt."  Then use the min StartDt and max EndDt from that table to build a second table with one column "Dt" of all Dates between those (like a numbers table but with dates).  Then join that second table to your first table, on Dt between StartDt and EndDt, selecting Distinct.  The result is table 3, and it contains all the individual dates you want.  Then inner join table 3 back to your source table.  As mentioned by crokusek, should have index on your source table date field